# jQuery show/hide button where character count is 250

Tags: jquery, show-hide

Say I have a paragraph of text that has 500 or so words. But I'd like to only show 250 characters and display a show button to expand the area to show the rest. Is this possible but rounding the characters upto the fullest word (so we dont have words cut off).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since theres no attemped code... i'm only proving pseudo code as i dont agree with doing someones work for them..
  - get the length

- If the length > 250 edit the content to show the rest

This is easily done.. have a try.. make a fiddle then maybe more people will help out?

Comment: p.s. have a try, make a fiddle and al give you a hand !

Comment: *pseudo. Sudo is something entirely different :-)

Comment: This is not what the OP wants. Who says anybody was typing anything? He said he *has* a paragraph. What he wants is to have a div that displays a certain amount of its contents, and has the option to display the rest if needed.

Comment: Ok well rather than listening just check the length?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jquery, i would suggest using a plugin for this

Many "Ellipsis" plugin only show the three dots, as per previous answers here on the same subject, without allowing to show the rest of thext.

On the other hand, I found this one : http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/ Which looks fine, at least the demo page shows the behaviour you expect